# How to compare two array of objects by mutiple properties using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

I have two array of objects in which if property `grp` from arrobj1 is

same as `SERVICE` and `ISACTIVE is true` from arrobj2, then return array of object using

javascript

```
Tried

let result = arrobj1.filter(e=> 
 arrobj2.some(i=> i.ISACTIVE===true && e.grp === i.SERVICE);
);

var arrobj1=[
  {
    id:"SetupFS",
    grp:"fs",
    title: "xxx"
  },
  {
    id:"ExtendFS",
    grp:"fs",
    title: "yyy"
  },
  {
    id:"RebootServer",
    grp:"os",
    title: "yyy"
  },
]

var arrobj2=[
{id:1, ISACTIVE:true, TASK:'SetupFS', SERVICE: "fs" }, 
{id:2, ISACTIVE:false, TASK:'RebootServer', SERVICE:"os" }, 
{id:3, ISACTIVE:false, TASK:'ExtendFS', SERVICE: "fs" }, 
]
```

```
Expected Result

[
 {
    id:"SetupFS",
    grp:"fs",
    title: "xxx"
  }
 
]
```

Comment: Your expected output meets the requirements you outlined at the start of the question, but I suspect you also want to check if `e.id === i.TASK`

Comment: Please update your question and explain why you feel your code is not right? If you get unexpected output, then what exactly is not according to the rules you have set out at the start?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `filter` for second item, you need to check if the item with corresponding `index` in `arrobj1` with `grp` value equal to `SERVICE` value in `arrobj2`

```js
var arrobj1=[
  {
    id:"SetupFS",
    grp:"fs",
    title: "xxx"
  },
  {
    id:"ExtendFS",
    grp:"fs",
    title: "yyy"
  },
  {
    id:"RebootServer",
    grp:"os",
    title: "yyy"
  },
]

var arrobj2=[
{id:1, ISACTIVE:true, TASK:'SetupFS', SERVICE: "fs" }, 
{id:2, ISACTIVE:false, TASK:'RebootServer', SERVICE:"os" }, 
{id:3, ISACTIVE:false, TASK:'ExtendFS', SERVICE: "fs" }, 
]

let result = arrobj2.filter((item, i) => 
 item.SERVICE === arrobj1[i].grp
);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks but should INACTIVE is true ,

Comment: @code44, so you need to filter in `arrobj2` not `arrobj1`, I just update the answser.

Comment: ,, not like that, i should filter from arrobj1 only, if arrobj1.grp === arrobj2.service and arrobj.isactive === true then return that arrobj

Comment: `I used this as arrobj2 , var arrobj2=[
{id:1, ISACTIVE:true, TASK:'SetupFS', SERVICE: "fs" }, 
{id:2, ISACTIVE:false, TASK:'RebootServer', SERVICE:"os" }, 
{id:3, ISACTIVE:true, TASK:'ExtendFS', SERVICE: "fs" }, 
]
used this code
let result = arrobj1.filter((item, i) => 
  item.grp === arrobj2[i].SERVICE && arrobj2[i].ISACTIVE === true
);
`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method

```
// gets two results wit the equals
let filteredList = [];
for (const item of arrobj1) {
 // include TASK === item.id to get the expected answer
 const inArray = arrobj2.find(e => e.ISACTIVE && e.TASK === item.id &&  e.SERVICE === item.grp);
  if (inArray) {
    filteredList.push(item)
  }
}

console.log(filteredList)
```

with filters in the question it returns two items
e => e.ISACTIVE &&  e.SERVICE === item.grp

```
0: Object
   id: "SetupFS"
   grp: "fs"
   title: "xxx"
1: Object
   id: "ExtendFS"
   grp: "fs"
   title: "yyy"
```

Hope it helps

but if this is not what was expected, I'll delete the answer

Comment: Hi Azzy thanks for reply, if pass the arrobj2 as var arrobj2=[
{id:1, ISACTIVE:true, TASK:'SetupFS', SERVICE: "fs" }, 
{id:2, ISACTIVE:false, TASK:'RebootServer', SERVICE:"os" }, 
{id:3, ISACTIVE:false, TASK:'ExtendFS', SERVICE: "fs" }, 
] `, not working

Comment: is it not working with the second condition
const inArray = arrobj2.find(e => e.ISACTIVE && e.TASK === item.id &&  e.SERVICE === item.grp);
I had tried it on code sandbox, it was giving the right result, 
I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: may i know why i need to check ` // include TASK === item.id to get the expected answer` instead of two conditions

Comment: With  e.ISACTIVE && e.SERVICE === item.grp it gets two results as given in the answer,  the id of the items in first array matches with the TASK  items in the second array, when viewed visually, you can use the filter condition which you feel serves the purpose